# how to traverse and get the text value of the sibling of a parent in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, parent, siblings

Is there a way to get the text of the sibling of a parent in Cypress?

[image]

I tried this but cypress can't find the element of the siblings

```
cy.get('[role="switch"]')
  .parentsUntil('[class="v-list-item__icon px-3"]')
  .siblings('[class="v-list-item__title px-3"]')
```

Comment: You can use [`prev()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/prev). Also, if you're targeting by class use a class selector, not an attribute one: `.parentsUntil('.v-list-item__icon.px-3')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

`parentsUntil()` gives you all parents, *excluding* the one you specified in the selector, and they are in reverse order.

So you want the `.last()` of the elements selected by `.parentsUntil('[class="v-list-item__icon px-3"]')`, and you want it's `.parent()` - which is actually `[class="v-list-item__icon px-3"]`.

```js
cy.get('[role="switch"]')
  .parentsUntil('[class="v-list-item__icon px-3"]')
  .last()                               // child of class="v-list-item__icon px-3"
  .parent()                             // div with class="v-list-item__icon px-3"
  .siblings('[class="v-list-item__title px-3"]')
  .should('have.text', 'Type')
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you @Lola Ichingbola